# How to set the C standard for errors shown

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have Visual Studio 2019 and I want to change the C standard for the Visual Studio internal compiler that shows me the errors live in the document.

The real compiler and everything is already set up. My only problem is that the errors in Visual Studio and the errors that gcc shows in the Compile log are not the same.

I think the reason is that I use c99 and Visual Studio uses c89, but I'm not sure.

I already tried [this](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/%7Epatt/22f.460n/labs/vstudio.html) but it didn't work, since there is no language property page in my projects. Actually none of the settings mentioned there exist in my projects.

I tried to look into the Code Analysis tool, but my project can't use it either.